# Bash scripting - output lines with matching pattern AND the count

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to find the number of lines in a file that match a certain pattern and find the number of lines that matched. For example, if my file were

> test1 type1 random1
>
> test2 type2 bird
>
> dog cat random

I want to find the lines that have "random" and the number of lines. Ideally, the output would be something like

> test1 type1 random1
>
> dog cat random
>
> 2

I know how to use grep to do either of these tasks individually, but if I'm working with a large file, I'd prefer to not read the file twice. I'd also like to stay away from making an additional temp file to store the results of grep.

Is there a command and/or a simple function I can write to achieve these results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{total=0} {if(/random/) {total+=1; print $0;}}END{print total}' input_file
```

Comment: Or with perl: `perl -nle 'if (/random/) { $count++; print } END { print $count || 0 }'`

Comment: You could omit the `BEGIN` block; the variable `total` will be initialized to zero when it is first referenced.  You could also put the match `/random/` outside the `{…action…}`, and use a `++` increment.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/random/{count++;print}END{print count}' file
```

If match found, increment the counter and print.
Print the count at the end.

Comment: This is nice and compact.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

```
$ cat t.txt
foo: bar
foo: quux
bar: baz
$ awk -v regex='bar' '$0 ~ regex { count++; print } END {print count}' t.txt
foo: bar
bar: baz
2
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the `awk` solutions here, but as always, there's more than one way to skin a cat. If you number the output lines with `nl` it's easy to see  how many matches you got.

```
grep stuff from files | nl
```

Getting exactly the output you specified in the question is a simple matter of postprocessing (though I would not bother).  Pipe to a simple `sed` script to remove the line number, then print the latest removed number at the end.

```
grep stuff from files |
nl |
sed -n 'h                    # Keep a copy in hold space
     s/^ *[1-9][0-9]*\t//p   # Print without number
     $!b                     # Unless at last line, we're done
     x                       # Retrieve from hold space
     s/\t.*//p'              # Print only line number
```

(If your `sed` dialect does not recognize `\t` as a literal tab, or cannot cope with comments on the same line, you'll need to adapt this.  In most shells, you can type a literal tab with ctrl-V tab.)

Comment: Um, because you want to see the actual matches, and don't want to rerun a potentially expensive search?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Then I suggest you remove your comments after the first one. When you read this I will already have removed my  comments from the thread.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` variant for this problem statement is more optimized. But if you don't want to use awk, here is grep+wc variant:

In case, you want to use grep, instead of awk.

```
$ grep -F random random.log | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
test1 type1 random1
dog cat random
2
```